# How to display different flash.message in different style in GSP page

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-2.0

I have to display different messages using flash.message, some of them have to be in different color, So How to distinguish the flash.message and display them in different color in GSP

Comment: How about using of different variables in flash scope? E.g. flash.errorMessage, flash.successMessage, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the view page code to view error and suces msg in different style

```
   <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message" role="status" style="font-size: medium;color: green;">${flash.message}</div>
    </g:if>
    <g:if test="${flash.warning}">
        <div class="message_error" style="font-size: medium;color: red;">${flash.warning}</div>
    </g:if>
```

the controller code to call respective label
if scues:

```
flash.message = message(code: 'Applied Successfully', args: [message(code: 'hrIrRegistration.label', default: 'HrIrRegistration'), hrIrAplcJobAppldLkInstance.id])
                redirect(controller: "hrIrRegistration", action: "showVcnyForApplcnt", id: params.hrIrVcncyIdHrIrVcncy.id)
```

if error:

```
flash.warning = message(code: 'You have already Applied in this vacancy', args: [message(code: 'hrIrRegistration.label', default: 'HrIrRegistration'), hrIrAplcJobAppldLkInstance.id])
                redirect(controller: "hrIrRegistration", action: "showVcnyForApplcnt", id: params.hrIrVcncyIdHrIrVcncy.id)
```